# GTK in java using windows

Tags: gtk

can i use GTK in java using windows?Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 5):

> Unlike most other GTK+ bindings, there is no version available for Microsoft Windows.

According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java-gnome).

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried, but there's [JavaGtk](https://github.com/JavaGtk/JavaGtk) on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [java-gtk](https://github.com/bailuk/java-gtk), a recent new contender.
To get started under Windows, follow the [documentation](https://github.com/bailuk/java-gtk/blob/main/doc/windows.md).