# Running GTK through Java on Windows

Tags: java, c, windows, gcc, gtk

I've found that there is only one [project](https://github.com/JavaGtk/JavaGtk) that allows to do this (from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18522135/1418097)).
I'm trying to get it working (just for fun). So far I have built `java` code via `Eclipse` (had to add `slf4j` jars to build path), then modified `build_jni.bat` and run it without error messages, so I think it did its work too.

Now I'm at the third sub-step of the README, which says `"Build the c portion next.  You will need to point the gcc compiler and linker to the /include and /lib folders of the extracted GTK bundle."`. I'm not quite sure what to do next... there is no "`makefile`" or similar thing. Should I throw files to compiler and hope it will figure out everything from scratch? Or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was my plan to release a bundle of completed binaries so that users don't have to build everything from scratch but there didn't seem to be much interest in the project so I moved on to something else.  Maybe I'll take another look at it now that there is a link from StackOverflow.

I used Eclipse to build everything using the MinGW GCC toolchain.  I remember that it took a while to get MinGW setup and configured to work with Eclipse and I don't recall all the steps right now.

Once it is installed and configured you will need to modify the project settings:

C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> GCC C Compiler -> Includes

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\include"
"${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/src/main/c/include}"
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\include\win32"
"C:\data\Projects\java-gtk\gtk3\include\gtk-3.0"
"C:\data\Projects\java-gtk\gtk3\include\glib-2.0"
"C:\data\Projects\java-gtk\gtk3\lib\glib-2.0\include"
"C:\data\Projects\java-gtk\gtk3\include\cairo"
"C:\data\Projects\java-gtk\gtk3\include\pango-1.0"
"C:\data\Projects\java-gtk\gtk3\lib\gtk-3.0\include"
"C:\data\Projects\java-gtk\gtk3\include\gdk-pixbuf-2.0"
"C:\data\Projects\java-gtk\gtk3\include\atk-1.0"
```

C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> MinGW C Linker -> Libraries

```
gtk-3
cairo
pango-1.0
gobject-2.0
glib-2.0
gdk-3
atk-1.0
gdk_pixbuf-2.0
```

C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> MinGW C Linker -> Library search path

```
"C:\data\Projects\java-gtk\gtk3\lib"
```

You will need to change some of the paths above depending on where you extracted the gtk bundle.

The project is not complete and there might not be enough content to build a complete UI.  But you are welcome to add any additional pieces you think are necessary.

Comment: Thank you, and welcome to SO! :D
I will try again when I have some time.

Comment: I added all includes (but there was no `...\lib\gtk-3.0\include`), and there is one error left:
`fatal error: glibconfig.h: No such file or directory` (at gtk-bundle/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h, line 34) What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what could be wrong.  I checked the gtk bundle and glibconfig.h is located where it should be at /lib/glib-2.0/include/ so as long as that path is included in the includes list it should find it.  I would recheck the paths where you extracted the bundle and the paths in the includes list.